# How to get dimensions of double[,]?

Tags: c#

I have an array like `images[,]`. I created it like `[a,b]`. But I want to check the dimensions of it later. How can I check it? When I write `images.Length`, it gives something weird. Is there a way to get both `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
int dim1 = images.GetLength(0);
int dim2 = images.GetLength(1);
```

See [`Array.GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) on MSDN